# Actionmailer not delivering mail, with rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I am trying to make an application, that sends an email when user registers.

i put in the smtp settings for gmail in the config/application.rb file and the mail function looks like

```
mail(:to => "me@me.com", :subject => "Mail!", :from => "another@me.com", :content_type => "text/html")
```

now when i see the logs, i see that it says mail has been sent, but i never receive any mail at all...

also, when i call the mail deliver function, `Emails.signed(@user).deliver`, the form page does not redirect, but it works if i comment out the email sending code that is either

```
Emails.signed(@user).deliver
```

or

```
mail(:to => "me@me.com", :subject => "Mail!", :from => "another@me.com", :content_type => "text/html")
```

Thanks :)

Edit: development.rb

```
App::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/environment.rb

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request.  This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the webserver when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil.
  config.whiny_nils = true

  # Show full error reports and disable caching
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_view.debug_rjs             = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

end
```

Comment: Are you trying to send it on development or production? please paste the `development.rb` or `production.rb` file.

Comment: i am in development mode...

i added the development.rb

Comment: Hey please check the following post, and let us know if you continue having problems. http://asciicasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3 It should work if you have properly set up your gmail smtp settings.

Comment: Hi, this is the same tutorial i refered to... thats what is leaving me puzzled... maybe development mode is not allowing mails to be sent, even though i set set mail_delivery to true?

Comment: How are you sure, that mail not deliver ? By default, all mail aare sent by sendmail. So it's maybe on your sendmail queue system. In your output, there are no configuration of mail to do.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Somewhat late, but nevertheless maybe this will save someone a few hours of head banging. This is probably only relevant to sending emails from gmail.
First, in order to help debugging the situation, set the following line in development.rb to true (assuming you're in development mode):

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

This will make ActionMailer not to silently ignore errors.
When I did that, I realized gmail is refusing my username and password. 
I then went to my configuration file where I put all the Action Mailer config directives (for me it was in development.rb, there is probably a better place to put it), and noticed that :user_name was set to "admin" rather than "admin@thedomain.com". Changing it solved the problem. Here is my corrected part of development.rb:

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => 'thedomain.com',
  :user_name            => 'admin@thedomain.com',
  :password             => '<password>',
  :authentication       => 'plain',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true  }
```

References:

http://forums.pragprog.com/forums/43/topics/541
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

Answer (score 7):

Another thing not to forget: you have to restart the application after making changes in your environment config files. when using passenger this can quickly be missed :)

that's what solved my "problem" when ActionMailer didnt want to send emails without showing any errors..

Comment: I felt like a fool for realizing that I had not restarted my server. It worked perfectly after I restarted my server. 

However, my log file was creating logs that had the exact same information before and after I edited my code which made me think it was recognizing my changes.

I believe this was because I needed to restart the server before it actually started raising delivery errors, which was my change to the config file. So if you have told it to start raising delivery errors but have not restarted the problem won't be visible until you restart the server.

Answer (score 6):

The things written here did not help me.

I am using Rails 3.2.8 and I spent several hours trying to figure this out and it was very simple in the end. I forgot to call `.deliver()` on the `Mail::Message` object that is returned by `mail(:to => @user.email, :subject => 'Welcome to the Site')` method call.

Just leave everything like it is specified in [official RoR tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html).

That is, in your development/production environment files, make a section like:

```
  # mailer
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
      port:                 587,
      domain:               'gmail.com',
      user_name:            '<username>@gmail.com',
      password:             '<password>',
      authentication:       'plain',
      enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
```

And then you subclass ActionMailer::Base, for example like this:

```
class InfoMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "<username>@gmail.com"

  def welcome_user_and_send_password(user, password)
    default_url_options = self.default_url_options()


    @user = user
    @password = password
    @url = default_url_options[:host]
    mail(:to => @user.email, :subject => 'Welcome to the Site').deliver()
  end

end
```

After that, you can simply use this `InfoMailer` method from your code like a class method:

```
InfoMailer.welcome_user_and_send_password(user, password)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the test environment, be sure to comment out this line of code in environments/test.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
```