# Duplicate events in passenger, in websocket-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, websocket, passenger

I am using phusion passenger version 4.0.35

my websocket_rails.rb file

```
WebsocketRails.setup do |config|

config.log_level = :debug
config.log_internal_events = false

if Rails.env.production?
config.standalone = true
else
config.standalone = false
end
config.synchronize = false
end
```

In a normal controller i am using like this

```
connection1 = WebsocketRails.users[one_user_id]
connection1.send_message :online, @reply.to_json(:methods => required_methods)
connection2 = WebsocketRails.users[another_other_user_id]
connection2.send_message :online, @reply.to_json(:methods => required_methods)
```

in the client side

```
var socket_path = document.domain + ":3001" + '/websocket'

var dispatcher = new WebSocketRails(socket_path)

dispatcher.bind('online', function(data){
.................
..................................
}
```

Problem is I get response twice while I am calling send_message on the controller both th user gets the response twice.

Another thing that it works great in the development in normal server mode which runs on thin.

Answer (score 0):

can you please use the .deliver function

[Actionmailer not delivering mail, with rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392282/actionmailer-not-delivering-mail-with-rails-3) this will help you and let me know

Comment: The issue is not about ActionMailer at all.

Comment: yes this issue is about the actionmailer. its related to the realtime push notification system while in my case client side receive json response from server.